# why I am not getting any outputs

Tags: shell, for

```
for items in *
do 
    if [ -f items ]
    then
        echo $items
    fi
done
```

Look at my directory [image] As you can see my directory isn't empty but, when I run above code it isn't printing anything..

> ┌──(istiak㉿kali)-[~/ShellProgramming]
>
> └─$ ./practice.sh

Comment: You forgot the `$` in `-f items` (compare with `echo $items`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) for his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643875/why-i-am-not-getting-any-outputs?noredirect=1#comment1205748_643875).

Here's the answer

```
for items in *
do 
    if [ -f "$items" ]
    then
        printf '%s\n' "$items"
    fi
done
```

Comment: FYI, with the `zsh` shell, the same can be done with `print -rC1 -- *(N-.)`, there `print -rC1` prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn and `(N-.)` is a glob qualifier that selects files whose type is *regular* (`.`) determined after symlink resolution (`-`) like `[`'s `-f` does (and `N` to enable nullglob for that one glob)